# Could not locate a function present in QuoteValidator.php file

Tags: magento2

I was trying to create an order programatically in magento 2 but I was getting an error.
**The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.**

The code that I am using to create an order is working on staging platform but not in live. This is where I have asked a question regarding this.

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/shipping-method-is-enabled-in-admin-but-still-getting-this-issue-the-shipping-m
```

Now I am trying to debug this issue. This is the error that is thrown in the browser.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again. in /home/rainmanstag/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteValidator.php:107 Stack trace: #0 /home/rainmanstag/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/SubmitQuoteValidator.php(50): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator->validateBeforeSubmit(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor)) #1 /home/rainmanstag/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(501): Magento\Quote\Model\SubmitQuoteValidator->validateQuote(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor)) #2 /home/rainmanstag/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(456): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor), Array) #3 /home/rainmanstag/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor)) #4 /home/rainm in /home/rainmanstag/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteValidator.php on line 107
```

Now while trying to debug this, I have located a function in the file

```
/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteValidator.php
```

This is the function that is throwing the above error.

```
/**
 * Validates quote before submit.
 *
 * @param Quote $quote
 * @return $this
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */
public function validateBeforeSubmit(QuoteEntity $quote)
{
    if ($quote->getHasError()) {
        $errors = $this->getQuoteErrors($quote);
        throw new LocalizedException(__($errors ?: 'Something went wrong. Please try to place the order again.'));
    }

    foreach ($this->quoteValidationRule->validate($quote) as $validationResult) {
        if ($validationResult->isValid()) {
            continue;
        }

        $messages = $validationResult->getErrors();
        $defaultMessage = array_shift($messages);
        if ($defaultMessage && !empty($messages)) {
            $defaultMessage .= ' %1';
        }
        if ($defaultMessage) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__($defaultMessage, implode(' ', $messages)));
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

In the above function in if condition we can see there is a condition. **$quote->getHasError()**
I am looking for the function getHasError(), but could not find it. Plz guide me where I shall look for this function because I feel this is what is giving the shipping error.
So I want to debug this function and find the root cause, or any other guidance to help me find the root cause for this issue.

Comment: getHasError() is not the function, it just the model's setter and getter, like in any model you have to get the data, then you do $model->getName(), or anything else.

Comment: So there should be a setter for this function like setHasError() or setError(), could you help me locate that.

Comment: You can check the condition if getHasError() return $this